# Is there anything in Android like the appSettings in Asp.net?

Tags: android

I need to store a few values that are going to be use in several activities. I know could easily create a `Constants` class , a Interface or extend the `Application` class and put those constants there.
But not wanting to reinvent the wheel, I want to ask you if Android have something like **appSettings** in Asp.net or the **Application Descriptor** that we had in the old Java Me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do these values change or are they constant?

Comment: They're all constants

Comment: See if this is what you want http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using constants, there are two solutions:

1. Create an interface or class with `public static final` fields.
2. Create a XML resource file. See [Resource Types](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/available-resources.html) for details about the resource types.

Personally I prefer 1 for constants that are used in my Java code because 2 requires a `Context` object and calls to `getResources()`. This just makes for more code than is really necessary.

Note that I don't give SharedPreference as a possible solution. This is because SharedPreferences should be used to store calculated or user data rather than constant values.

Comment: There's a lot of opinions on whether is right or not to use a class , but since it is used a lot in the Android docs, I'm accepting your answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

[Complete Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Comment: Not enough reputation to comment.

Comment: Yes I know SharedPreferences , but I just wanted to know if there was a file , perhaps something like the strings.xml

Comment: @emaNoN note the changes I made to make it less of a comment. The link to the docs was wrong

Comment: The problem with SharedPreferences is that I need to set the value for those constants somewhere in the java code and since these constants are not specifically related to one class I don't think it'd be a good idea to set the values in a specific class

Comment: You could set them in OnCreate() of your main activity.